# Can we add binary raw data to a <form>?

Tags: javascript, base64, forms

Is it possible to add binary raw data to a form, e.g. in this `data` field:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="data" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

?

In my use case, I want to export an image from a `canvas` to JPEG with [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), then decode the base64 **to binary data**, add the binary data to the `<form>`, which will be ready for submitting.

Why do I want to **not** just post the base64-encoded data? Because I would like to save 1/3 of uploading time for client / bandwidth for server, and it is well known base64 is bigger than binary data of a factor 1.333.

Comment: Assemble the form data in javascript ([FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)) and add the binary data ([Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)).

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/45698370/6160662 will help.

Comment: `var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("data", new Blob([data], { type:"application/octet-stream" }));`

Comment: @transporter_room_3 is it possible to add it to `document.getElementById('data')` and use a normal <form> submit, or does this necessarily require AJAX?

Comment: @Viney this uses AJAX, is it possible also with a standard <form> submit?

Comment: It's more complicated than that, base64 is used in browser to avoid [Delimiter_collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision) .What if your binary string happens to have `&` in it when you have `www-form-urlencoded` <form>? It would mess up the whole form.`multipart/form-data` <form> might be some hope but if you ever looked such form at a transport level you would notice user submitted values being separated by string like `------WebKitFormBoundarysomerandomstring` *somerandomstring* is calculated carefully because the enveloped data withing it is sent verbatim.

Comment: @Viney I think you can post an answer with all these detailed interesting informations! Also, this seems to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51122589, but I don't know if it handles 100% successfully the corner cases you mentioned. What do you think?

Comment: You can go with the solution you pointed there's no place for delimiter collision when you let browser handle the stuff. Formdata is one of the object just for such use and it will be 100% reliable regardless the nature of data.Under the hood browser will use `multipart/form-data` but the boundary is calculated intelligently making sure it doesn't collide with any of payload data.If you inspect the POST request in devtools you can see that in action.

Comment: @Basj, I've added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your form

```
<form action="something.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Peter">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Quill">
  <input type="file" name="photo">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is how it gets sent

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybHHp9cSVfgrymPhN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstname"

Peter
------WebKitFormBoundarybHHp9cSVfgrymPhN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastname"

Quill
------WebKitFormBoundarybHHp9cSVfgrymPhN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarybHHp9cSVfgrymPhN--
```

Every form field's value is enveloped the boundary is calculated intelligently by the browser for that it goes over the entire form textbox, textareas etc (including raw file bytestream of the file inputs) 
all this in order to avoid [Delimiter collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#Delimiter_collision).Browsers will prefix the boundary with their respective vendor prefix like webkit here but in the end it always be a reliable delimiter.

Now even if you get your hands on this low level assembling of data, creating a really reliable delimiter will be a hefty task if you happen to have file inputs to worry about.That's why you should let browser handle such stuff the suggested Formdata based solution goes well with this.

`enctype='multipart/form-data'` is the only mechanism to send data regardless of it's nature all other enctype (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,`text/plain`) just support ASCII transfer.`entype`(s) are essentially a way of telling which scheme the browser should use to submit a form but the scheme itself isn't limited to mere forms as you can see Formdata using the same.